# Why is a set of functions $v(t)$ dense in $L^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was going through the following paper: http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/AAA/Volume2011/142128.pdf

In page 6, immediately after equation (3.15), its written that "functions of the form $v(t)$ are dense in $L^2\,$". I have been looking for proofs online which verifies the above statement but unable to find one. I would appreciate if someone can direct me to a link or explain with PROOF of how the functions of the form $v(t)$ are dense in $L^2$.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you at least briefly describe what the functions are? It it best if questions are mostly self-contained.